# How to get cross browser images the same color

Tags: browser, png, image, gif, jpeg

I've had long standing issues with images being different shades on different browsers - for example on OSX I can make a purple or green box and it will look different on chrome than safari. I have tried exporting as png8, png32, gif, jpg, on and on and nothing changes. I'd love to find some real color safe chart or hex generator or some info as to how I can get around this issue. I've tried using web safe color palettes with same issue. It's really frustrating having a logo look great on one browser and off on another. Also matching CSS to an img will work on one but not the other.

**More tests:**

The answer about color management led me to a lot to read but doesn't seem to be the issue - both safari 6 and current chrome have color management yet they render images different hues. I made a test of about 10 images exports (gif exact, jpeg, png24, png8, gif adaptive, etc) and did the same in both fireworks and photoshop cs6. The result - both app export different colors (something I suspected as PS exports in sRGB I think and I am not sure about FW as it has no settings) - however most images, regardless of app export. render differently in the browsers. What is of concern is that while chrome's images pretty much matched the css color, none of safari's images (21 of them total!) came even close to the css hex that I used in both a web css test and to define the color in the apps.

I have uploaded the screenshot - the top is safari and bottom chrome - the top left corner is the css only and all the rest are the various exports from both photoshop and fireworks using most export options.

http://www.pictureshoster.com/files/6wp6irm154cre3faop2.png

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this has to do with color management. Some browsers like Firefox or Safari support color management.

You could try to temporarily disable color management in Firefox by going to `about:config` and setting `gfx.color_management.mode` to 0.

You can find more information about firefox color management here:
http://www.metalvortex.com/blog/2012/03/16/831.html